# Need RegEx Find & Replace to Ignore Code Characters in String

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Working in DreamWeaver, I'm needing to swap out the closing /p tag on a large number of strings throughout a manuscript, some of which have a closing /span tag in the string.  When my RegEx method encounters the /span tag, it ignores the entire string. Here's an example:

My beginning and ending identifiers are a placeholder tag I've created (for another purpose) at the beginning of the string and the /p tag at the end, like this:

```
<!--b-->Tuesday:</span> Advent Weekday [2]</p>
```

My RegEx search string is:

```
<!--b-->([^>]*)</p>
```

which should work, but when it sees the /span tag, it passes over the entire string.

How can I get my RegEx search method to overlook the /span tag, or any other tag, in a string I need to effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--b-->((?:(?!</p>).)*)</p>
```

should work if there are no newlines to be matched. If that is the case, use

```
<!--b-->((?:(?!</p>)[\s\S])*)</p>
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # Start of group
 (?!</p>)   # Assert that it's impossible to match a closing p tag here
 .          # Match any character
)*          # repeat as often as possible
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you, Tim!